# How to decrease CRF++ feature function set?

Tags: nlp, parts-of-speech, corpora

I have a problem with the [CRF++ Package](http://crfpp.sourceforge.net/). CRF++ cannot handle large training parts-of-speech corpora (large tagset and large number of words).

In fact, the number of feature functions automatically generated by CRF++ is very large, which extremely increases the training time. So, what is the best solution for reducing the size of  the feature function set?

Comment: What are the automatic features like? Are there any configuration parameters for CRF++?

Comment: This notation (http://crfpp.sourceforge.net/) can help you